# Qt Error building package 'fromString' is not a member of 'QKeySequence'

Tags: qt, ubuntu, build, makefile, cross-compiling

I can compile my package ( maliit ) with the QtSDK x86 GCC and qmake just fine within QtCreator. I am now attempting to cross-compile the pacakge for ARM. My Qmake and Qt libraries were built with Buildroot using the following configuration:

```
cd /home/user/project/output/buildroot/build/qt-4.8.1; PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR="/home/user/project/output/buildroot/host/usr/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/sysroot" PKG_CONFIG="/home/user/project/output/buildroot/host/usr/bin/pkg-config" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/user/project/output/buildroot/host/usr/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/pkgconfig:" MAKEFLAGS="w --  -j1" ./configure -silent -force-pkg-config -separate-debug-info -xplatform qws/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++- -opensource -confirm-license -largefile -no-qt3support -nomake examples -nomake demos -depths 16,32 -qt-gfx-linuxfb -no-gfx-transformed -no-gfx-qvfb -qt-gfx-vnc -no-gfx-multiscreen -no-gfx-directfb -no-mouse-pc -no-mouse-linuxtp -qt-mouse-linuxinput -qt-mouse-tslib -no-mouse-qvfb -no-kbd-tty -qt-kbd-linuxinput -no-kbd-qvfb -debug -shared -little-endian -embedded arm -no-gif -no-libmng -system-zlib -qt-libjpeg -qt-libpng -no-libtiff -qt-freetype -dbus -qdbus -no-openssl -no-sql-sqlite -no-xmlpatterns -no-multimedia -no-audio-backend -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -svg -no-webkit -no-script -no-scripttools -no-javascript-jit -no-stl -no-declarative -glib -no-gfx-qnx -no-kbd-qnx -no-mouse-qnx -no-xinerama -no-cups -no-nis -no-accessibility -prefix /usr -plugindir /usr/lib/qt/plugins -hostprefix /home/user/project/output/buildroot/host/usr/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr -fast -no-rpath
```

When I try to cross-compile the package within QtCreator it makes it about halfway and then errors out at the Q_EMIT line in the following function:

```
void GlibDBusIMServerProxy::onInvokeAction(const QString &action,
                                           const QString &sequence)
{
    Q_EMIT invokeAction(action, QKeySequence::fromString(sequence));
}
```

The file definitely includes the header:

```
#include <QKeySequence>
```

Here is the entire build error:

```
glibdbusimserverproxy.cpp: In member function 'void GlibDBusIMServerProxy::onInvokeAction(const QString&, const QString&)':
glibdbusimserverproxy.cpp:230:33: error: 'fromString' is not a member of 'QKeySequence'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Desktop/maliit-framework/connection'
make[1]: *** [.obj/glibdbusimserverproxy.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/user/Desktop/maliit-framework'
make: *** [sub-connection-make_default-ordered] Error 2
12:51:08: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building project maliit-framework (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

I can follow the header from within the IDE and there is the correct definition under Public:

```
static QKeySequence fromString(const QString &str, SequenceFormat format = PortableText);
```

What could be wrong? I have used the cross-compiled libraries for quite a few other projects and it is working fine for those. How could it not find the 'fromString' static method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the option to the Qt configure command is causing the definition of the `QT_NO_SHORTCUT` macro, which replaces the general definition of the `QKeySequence` class by an empty class.

Comment: Perfect - my qconfig was enabling this macro. Thanks -